# 1970s scifi book about a worldwide endless war

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi

I read this in the mid 70s from my local library.

The book was set on a militarized world with two factions in an endless war. It may have been a future earth but I think it was set on an alien world. Very vague memory I'm afraid but I remember enjoying it very much and it's atmosphere of endless mayhem has stuck with me. It's among the first sci-fi I've read and I would love to rediscover it. It's not the Star Trek "A Taste of Armageddon" (although I do love that episode). I'm also fairly sure it wasn't *The Forever War* either.

Comment: Endless war is a common idea. We'd need to know a lot more to identify that story. What else can you remember? Were the participants human? What kinds of weapons and other technologies did they use? Were there civilians? Were there neutrals? Did the storytelling follow both sides or only one? Were the two factions divided by biology, culture, ideology,  nothing, etc.? Did some characters try to end the war, or to escape? Do you remember anything about the cover? … Try the [list on TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForeverWar).

Comment: and it's not this one came of Civ 2 i heard about?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I was 13/14 when I read it 40 years ago (aargh). It was more the atmosphere I remember. The protagonists were human and the war was hi tech (but not remote). The war conssted of huge battles with no consideration of casualties. Thanks for looking anyway...

Comment: Is this the one where the main character finds out that the `enemy` are human soldiers too? Both sides are fed the same propaganda to keep the war going for either population control or profit.

Comment: When I read your description, it reminded me of a short story I read in the mid-70's. But the most memorable element in that story is that time passes rapidly at the poles and more slowly as you go to the equator. That story is Traveller's Rest by David Masson.
See [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/short-story-war-where-speed-of-time-changes-with-distance-from-front-line).

Comment: I was about to suggest "Traveler's Rest" -- and did, in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211146/short-story-about-people-living-in-a-different-time-streams/212138#212138 .

Although the most gripping part, and most, of the story is about the time differences in each of the latitude belts, the hingepin of the story that drove the protagonist's life was the eternal war at one of the planet's poles.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be the legendary *Moderan* by David R. Bunch?

Atmospheric - check.
Future earth, not another planet.
Combatants were human... well, originally.
Huge battles, massive casualties - check.
Factions - many shifting alliances between the Strongholds.
Endless war  - check.

[image]

Comment: I've owned 'Moderan' as an ebook for several months now. I got it as part of a bundle deal. I've never looked at it or moved it into my TBR pile. However, after looking at this, it's gonna be my next read.

Comment: I missed the fact that this has come back into print since I wrote the suggested answer above. Something else for TBR-R (re-read) pile..

Comment: Have got a copy, on my bedside pile to be read soon. Will get back when read...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you mean [Bill, the Galactic Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill,_the_Galactic_Hero) by Harry Harrison? That was written in 1965 so not too far off.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'm familiar with most HH stuff...

Answer (score -4):

One possibility is **1984** by George Orwell.

Comment: Ah now, I'm not that muich of an eegit...

Comment: And there are three factions in that book, not two.

Comment: @Oldcat  True, but the book notes that typically two will gang up against the 3rd until they actually look like beating them, then one of the 'winning alliance' powers changes sides in order to keep the war going.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - but we've always been at war with Eurasia!