# Perpetual war sci-fi story from the 70s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, dystopia

So my dad was telling me the other day that he used to read a lot of short sci fi stories in the 70s and he mentioned one story in particular but has long since forgotten what it's called and who it's written by. I wondered if anyone else might have read it and could perhaps tell me the name of the story so that I can tell my dad or perhaps find a way of purchasing a copy as a neat gift. 
Here are some of the story elements he told me about:

- Two planets at war
- Both sides actually human
- Both sides fed the same propoganda that the enemy is alien
- Perpetual war created as a means of population control (and possibly helping economy because of weapons sales)
- Insignia and uniform changes for both sides occasionally to make the old threat seem like a new one.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/57018/21871 .

Comment: Throwing this one out as a possible.  "The Eternity Brigade" by Stephen Goldin.  https://www.amazon.com/Eternity-Brigade-Stephen-Goldin-ebook/dp/B003K16TSI

Comment: The only listed element that fits *The Eternity Brigade* is “both sides actually human”.