# What story is set on planet where time runs faster as one approaches the pole?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

short story (or novelette?) read in the 1960s or '70s, likely in an anthology from the 1950's plus or minus: planet where time ran faster as one approached the (north?) pole, and the language used by the characters became more abridged as part of that speed-up - a "war" was going on, perhaps because someone fired a missile over the pole and it came back at themselves?

Comment: Traveller's rest. I think this may be a duplicate.

Comment: @Fruitbat More than likely, yes, but please don't VTC before we have confirmation from the OP.

Comment: @MrLister Not sure of the exact procedure here then. I've posted a brief answer instead.

Comment: @Fruitbat The general rule is that story identification questions shouldn't be closed as duplicates until we're absolutely sure they're indeed duplicates. The reason being that there are many stories out there that are very similar to other stories, and the OP may simply be thinking about a different one than you are..

Comment: @MrLister OK, understood. (Probably could be made clearer in the help, though.)

Comment: @Fruitbat There's a [FAQ post on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) where this policy was decided upon.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks. Clearly I need to pay more attention to meta (or my memory).

Comment: aha, yes! - reading the other answer that must be it ... tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Traveller's Rest*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43952) by David Masson.

[More complete answer.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/identify-short-story-war-with-changing-time-speed-further-from-the-front)