# flat world, relativistic rotation speed, *NOT DISCWORLD*

Tags: story-identification

I recall a sci-fi story (probably 1950's) situated on a world where the rotational speed was so high that relativistic effects were involved near the equator... the further away you were, the weaker the effect. individuals' names were longer away from the equator, because you had more time to express things. and, there was an on-planet war. i recall the main character having a name like "Hadolarison" near the pole. Can anybody clue me the title/author?

Comment: Except for the time dilation being flipped (more time at the equator) and the scientific explanation for it, this sounds exactly like "Traveller's Rest".

Comment: In "Traveller's Rest" we meet H at the front, he is Had at the next waypoint south and, finally, Hadolarisóndamo when he settles down and gets married.

Comment: Also [Short story; war where speed of time changes with distance from front line](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/short-story-war-where-speed-of-time-changes-with-distance-from-front-line)

Comment: @JohnRennie The second one has an accepted answer, so I guess that one would be the basis for being a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for the fact that time compression is most severe at the *pole* and the fact that in the story the cause is never explained, you are almost definitely describing "[Traveller's Rest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43952)" (1965) by David I. Masson.

The reason I'm confident this is the correct story is that you have managed to exactly spell most of the protagonist's name.

H is a soldier fighting an unknown and unseen enemy.  Nobody on his side has ever seen the enemy, but as much as they fire weapons at the enemy, the enemy fires back just as hard.

At the front H can only see an east-west band about 100m wide in the north-south direction.  Further north than that and the light (coming from a source in slower time) is redshifted into the infra-red.  (They do have infra-red cameras that can see *slightly* further north.)  To the south, light coming from a faster time is blue-shifted into the ultraviolet.

H is Relieved, and takes a maglev back from the front, a few minutes later and a few miles south, Had gets off.  The time variation, he notes, is 1 minute here to 5 seconds at the front.  He is Hadol at the next stop, and Hadolar at the following one where he is mustered out.  Hadolaris spends a night at a guesthouse before moving on again.  **Hadolarisóndamo** settles down in Oluluetang where he approximates 19 days to less than 2 seconds at the front.

You may have erroneously recalled a scientific basis for the effect, since the implications are fairly scientifically investigated.  In addition to the effect on light, the flora and fauna in the more time-compressed areas are significantly less evolved, and the effect on weather is mentioned.

It was first published in *New Worlds SF*, September 1965 and subsequently anthologized in 2 "year's best" collections and many others since.  You can read it online at [Lightspeed Magazine](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/travellers-rest/).